# Ask for ubuntu os

Tags: xubuntu

I would like to kindly request please provide the Ubuntu OS to us. if you send it I can install it in 85 schools and in our office. Installation of this software will benefit over 3000 persons.

I hope your will send positive replay

Best Regard,

Comment: Here it is: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop Have fun! and xubuntu(as you question is tagged) http://xubuntu.org/getxubuntu/ (try the alternate of xubuntu for 12.04 for best results/compatibility with old computers)

Comment: Why did you tag this xubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

- Go to [Ubuntu's download page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop).
- Make your choice according to your preferred version (I recommend you Ubuntu 12.04 LTS) and your hardware - 64 bit or 32 bit.
- Choose how much or whether you will donate.
- Download.

Answer (score 1):

You can download ubuntu for free from [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop). If you want to buy ubuntu live cd, and by doing it support ubuntu development, you can order it [here](http://shop.canonical.com/product_info.php?products_id=976). Xubuntu can be downloaded for free [here](http://xubuntu.org/getxubuntu/). Ubntu is a great choice for schools, as it has all the tools available to download from ubuntu center. Just type *edubuntu*, and you will find educational packages.